# Plotting a 3D surface plot in Ploty (Python) is stretched / deformed

Tags: python, plotly

I am plotting a two dimensional function in Plotly. I am experiencing that the plot is stretched much into the height. (see picture below). In the layout, I already changed the values for height and width, but it has no influence on it.

That is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


x_test_d1 = np.linspace(-4,4,100)
x_test_d2 = np.linspace(-3,3,100)


grid_d1, grid_d2 = np.meshgrid(x_test_d1,x_test_d2)

z = 1.5*np.sin(grid_d1) - 0.1*(grid_d1-3)**2 +10 - 0.5*(grid_d2**2-2) + np.sin(grid_d2)*2


fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=grid_d1, y=grid_d2, z=z)])
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20),
    width=800, height=400)

fig.show()
```

and that is the resulting figure:

[image: Resulting figure that is stretched too much :D]

Thank you for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you can find [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/)

> width
> Code: fig.update_layout(width=)
> Type: number greater than or equal to 10
> Default: 700
> Sets the plot's width (in px).

Somewhat counterintuitively, sets size of webview/window plot is shown in, but doesn't affect size of plot.

After a bit of digging I found solution, you will be probably interested in, [here](https://plotly.com/python/3d-axes/)

```
fig.update_layout(scene_aspectmode='cube')
```

Full snippet looks like this:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


x_test_d1 = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
x_test_d2 = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)


grid_d1, grid_d2 = np.meshgrid(x_test_d1, x_test_d2)

z = (
    1.5 * np.sin(grid_d1)
    - 0.1 * (grid_d1 - 3) ** 2
    + 10
    - 0.5 * (grid_d2**2 - 2)
    + np.sin(grid_d2) * 2
)


fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=x_test_d1, y=x_test_d2, z=z)])
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20), scene_aspectmode="cube")

fig.show()
```